# Makefile $shell into variable sed expanded incorrectly?

Tags: sed, makefile

I'm having an issue trying to capture the output of a sed command in a makefile variable.

`JS_SRC:=$(shell sed -n 's@.*src="\([^"]*\.js\).*@\1@p' index.html)`

Which gives me

`sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to`s'
`

I've been trying to escape things and the like, but am always given that error.
All variations of escaping I have run, run fine from the terminal.
How does a makefile call the shell command?. `/usr/bin/sh -c "cmd?"` or something different?.

Somethings being interpolated but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 1):

`JS_SRC:=$(shell sed -n "s/.*src=\"\\([^\"]*\\.js\\).*/\\1/p" index.html)`

Appears to work. I figured this out via running `make -d` and seeing the process it was creating.

What was baffling is that it did different things with `'` vs `"` in the sed argument. `"` is run with `/bin/sh -c "args"` so I was able to tweak the escaping to get what I needed to appear there. Using `'` seems to invoke sed directly.

There is a whole heap of escaping, that i imagine is unnecessary (I don't need to interpolate variables in the sed expression, but it sends it to a shell I understand. So it will have to do ! :)